# Replacing an array key contents whilst preserving the full array - PHP

Tags: php, arrays, key

I want to replace the contents of array key [menu_order] with my new array part, whilst keeping the entire array together. Which way would be to replace that key?

**Original complete array**

```
variable - $full_array 

Array
(
    [menu_order] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [row_position] => 1
                    [row_identifier] => home
                    [original_row_position] => 1
                    [button_styling] => off
                    [tab] => self
                )

            [1] => Array
                (
                    [row_position] => 2
                    [row_identifier] => benefits
                    [original_row_position] => 2
                    [button_styling] => off
                    [tab] => self
                )
        )

    [policy] => Array
        (
            [override_privacy] => no
            [privacy_override_textarea] => 
        )

)
```

**[menu_order] new data**

```
variable - $menu_order_array_part 

Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [row_position] => 1
            [row_identifier] => home
            [original_row_position] => 1
            [button_styling] => off
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [row_position] => 2
            [row_identifier] => benefits
            [original_row_position] => 2
            [button_styling] => off
        )
)
```

I can't get the syntax correct for editing the original array whilst replacing a multidimensional array

Thanks,

D

Answer (score 1):

You can use the key.

```
$full_array['menu_order'] = $menu_order_array_part;
```